# How to make an Android App that can "govern" over other Android Apps

Tags: android

For example, there is a popular application called "Lookout Security & Antivirus" in Google market.

This application can show all the applications that access to your location, contacts, SMS, and MMS data.

I want to know the general idea behind how this can be done in Android (I am not asking for the source code!)

This application do not require root permission to do all of these, so I believe that Android SDK actually provides these functionalities?

Answer (score 3):

So there is some thing called as [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) which can give you information about [PackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) from where you can explore more and extract PERMISSION_GRANTED.

Comment: This open source project https://code.google.com/p/android-permission-explorer/source/browse/ uses that approach. it might be interesting to check out.

Comment: So, basically you can only use the information on what is listed under permission list? Is there any way you can check whether an application actually accessed sensitive information at run-time level?

Comment: No, I am not aware of any such way. To check it in runtime

Answer (score 1):

My idea would be to get a list of all installed packages (applications) and check what permissions they registered in their Manifest.

This can be done using the `PackageManager`-class, namingly it's [`getInstalledPackages()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages%28int%29), supplied with the [`GET_PERMISSIONS`-flag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#GET_PERMISSIONS).

```
PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
for (PackageInfo info : manager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS){
  for (PermissionInfo perm : info.permissions){
    // Check if your requested permission is in the list
  }
}
```